# Matlab Vector Interval

Tags: matlab, vector, intervals, numerical-methods

I'm working with numerical methods and decided to begin learning with the Matlab environment, my question is, how can I add to the generated interval of my vector the last number of the interval, e.g.:

```
vector = [-2.4:2.4]
```

this will result in these numbers inside the vector:

```
 -2.4000   -1.4000   -0.4000    0.6000    1.6000
```

so, I wanna know what are my options so that I can do this:

```
 -2.4000   -1.4000   -0.4000    0.6000    1.6000    2.4000
```

I need the interval between the numbers to be 1 and I don't know the exact size of the vector, so I can't use `linspace` function. Before coming here to ask, I've already searched about it, but really didn't find something that could help me.

Comment: The spacing between 1.6 and 2.4 is not 1. Since the whole interval has width 4.8, you can't split it into elements that differ by 1.

Comment: If you're asking how to go from -2.4 to 2.4 by increments of 1 and somehow include 2.4 in that while still keeping increments of 1... well clearly that's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the difference between the first element and the last element is not a multpiple of 1 you *cannot* have the interval between numbers be 1 for all. However, if your goal is to ensure that the last element is some particular number and are willing to compromise (it seems you do with 1.6 and 2.4), how about constructing `v` like this?

```
v1 = -2.4; v_last = 2.4;
v = v1 : v_last;
if v(end) ~= v_last
    v = [v, v_last];
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I was actually thinking that could be a way to guarantee the first and last numbers of the interval to be generated inside the vector, anyways, thanks again.

Comment: This seems like a silly thing to try and do, but since the OP wants it then you can do it far neater: `[-r:p:(r-p/3), r]` where in this case `r` is `2.4` and `p` is `1`.

Comment: @Dan, no, that won't work always. We don't know the OP starts at `-r`, and then will `r-p/100` be enough? But yes, a bit silly.

Comment: @s.bandara it's easy to tweak for that scenario